# issue for using javascript dynamic generate html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, web

I have javascript code like below, it used to dynamic generate html code.

```
"<td width=\"6%\">" +
"<a id=\"Pat_Meass_" +
i +
"\" onclick=\"populatePatMeass(" +
item.PAT_ID +
"," +
"tr_Pat_Id_" + i +
")\" onmouseover=\"\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\"" +
"title=\"SubFormIsNotEmpty\"" +
">" +
"PatMeas" +
"</a>" +
"</td>";
```

It generate html like below.

```
<td class="tableBody" width="6%">
<a id="Pat_Meass_0" title="SubFormIsNotEmpty" style="cursor: pointer; color: blue;" onmouseover="" onclick="populatePatMeass(37008,tr_Pat_Id_0)">PatMeas</a>
</td>
```

Acturally, the onclikc part, I would like it generate like below:

```
onclick="populatePatMeass(37008,"tr_Pat_Id_0")"
```

So, How to modify the code. Please help me out. Many thanks.

Comment: You should consider using templates to generate your HTML because that JS code is just hard to read.

Comment: `"'tr_Pat_Id_" + i +"'" +`

Comment: @Satpal  Your answer is correct! Thanks! BTW, how to quick work on this code, I hate this kind code convert. Is there any online tool can make life easy? thanks!!!

Comment: Either use templates or You can create and bind events using jQuery that will be much easier to maintain.

Comment: So, what do you mean templates? I have no idea about it, could you please give me a web link that shows me what it is, or some more explain on it?

Comment: for starters http://www.borismoore.com/2010/09/introducing-jquery-templates-1-first.html

Comment: @Satpal thanks a lot. Is there any tool can automatic do convert for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var s = "<td width='6%'>" +
"<a id='Pat_Meass_" +
i +
"' onclick=\"populatePatMeass('" +
item.PAT_ID +
"'," +
"'tr_Pat_Id_" + i +
"')\" style='cursor: pointer;'" +
"title='SubFormIsNotEmpty'" +
">" +
"PatMeas" +
"</a>" +
"</td>";
```